# MySQL can't accept my table

Tags: mysql, sql, create-table

I have used MySQL Workbench to model my table and somehow there's a logic error in the SQL to create the tables generated by the software.

Here are the codes:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `trickani_main`.`user`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `trickani_main`.`user` (
  `iduser` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `fb_id` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
  `email` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL ,
  `first_name` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL ,
  `gender` VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`iduser`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `fb_id_UNIQUE` (`fb_id` ASC) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `email_UNIQUE` (`email` ASC) )
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `trickani_main`.`quiz_list`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `trickani_main`.`quiz_list` (
  `id_quiz_list` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `difficult` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_quiz_list`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `trickani_main`.`user_quiz_list`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `trickani_main`.`user_quiz_list` (
  `iduser` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `id_quiz_list` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `level_reached` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`iduser`, `id_quiz_list`) ,
  INDEX `fk_quiz_list_user1_idx` (`iduser` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_user_quiz_list_quiz_list1_idx` (`id_quiz_list` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_quiz_list_user1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`iduser` )
    REFERENCES `trickani_main`.`user` (`iduser` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_user_quiz_list_quiz_list1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_quiz_list` )
    REFERENCES `trickani_main`.`quiz_list` (`id_quiz_list` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

As result I'm getting the following message:

> **#1005 - Can't create table 'trickani_main.quiz_level' (errno: 150)**

I don't get it! I can't see any error even by reading the code itself!

Any help?

Comment: I think you don't show us the `quiz_level` creation code...

Comment: Generally I find when Workbench is complaining its a foreign key issue. If you disable FKs and run does it pass?

Comment: Is this *all* of the code? Because the table `quiz_level` is not even referenced in the SQL you've given us.

Comment: Seems to work at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/340a7/2/0)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You might want to try making your PKs not unsigned.

See this question/answer: [Adding table with FOREIGN KEY to a MySQL database causes errno 150](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11414685/adding-table-with-foreign-key-to-a-mysql-database-causes-errno-150)

**Edit**: you might want to try either making all your PKs signed or all your PKs unsigned. My guess is that the definition for `quiz_level`, which isn't currently shown in your question, has a PK whose signedness differs from the other tables.

Comment: That is not the intention of the accepted answer to the question you've referenced. The issue is that the two fields involved in the FK relationship were not identical, one was `SIGNED` and the other `UNSIGNED`. The problem would have *also* been solved by changing the other field to `UNSIGNED`.

Comment: What did it turn out to be, OP?

Comment: Were you originally trying to create `quiz_level` with a signed or unsigned PK?

Answer (score 0):

your table seems to work here

you are mixing between database and the tables.
just use tables what u want to create.

[**sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ae97b)